# For a charged black hole, does the charge appear to lie on the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, charge

In considering a charged (Reissner–Nordström) black hole, I was trying to figure out if the charge acts as though it is at the singularity or rather behaves as though it is a surface charge density on the event horizon.

From a distance, the two cases would mostly appear the same, yet in close proximity, or for the Kerr situation one would definitely see the difference.

I ask, because I was thinking about Hawking radiation, and if you're near a charged black hole, my understanding is the radiation (not measurable for known black holes, too weak) would necessarily be charged in this case.

If you're near such an object giving off charged particles from the even horizon, would it not have to appear as though the charge lies on the event horizon? Otherwise one has a discontinuity in the behavior of the charge as calculated by someone measuring the electric field from outside.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Reissner-Nordstrom black holes are naked?

Comment: @tox123        It really depends upon how charged they are. There are two event horizons for the charged black hole, and for extreme charge, the singularity can, in theory (GR theory that is) become naked.